# Bridge interface across VMs to allow lan VM internet access

Tags: networking, network-interface, bridge

Is it possible to bridge interfaces across VMs?

I have three VMs with the following setup:

```
VM1
eth0:    public ip
eth0:0   private lan ip 172.22.xx.x1

VM2
eth0     no ip
eth0:0   private lan ip 172.22.xx.x2

VM3
eth0     no ip
eth0:0   private lan ip 172.22.xx.x3
```

And I want `VM2/VM3` to be able to access the internet via `VM1`. Any chance I can bridge `VM2/VM3 eth0:0` to `VM1 eth0` to achieve this?

Thanks.

**EDIT** - I am running CentOS 7 on my VMs

Comment: Why bridge? Set up VM1 to forward packets between its adapters, and set default route on VM2/3 to VM1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup VM1 become a Linux Router, enable Ipv4 Forwarding and setup NAT MASQUERADE. Then, you set default route on VM2/3 to VM1 and dont forget DNS Server.

Try following command:

```
ip route add default via 172.22.xx.x1 dev eth0:0
```

**Reference**

- http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/07/how-to-configure-ubuntu-as-router.html